# Most important "one" or "noun" in a formal sentence

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence

If I use "**one**" in a sentence, is it considered as formal or informal?

For example, what I want to say is the following:

> There are many points that must be taken into consideration.
>       Nevertheless, there is missing the most important **"one"**, which is...

or

> There are many points that must be take into consideration.
>       Nevertheless, there is missing the most important **"point"**, which is...

Which of these senteces is correct, if I want to say this sentence in a formal way? Or are both considered formal?

Comment: Using existential 'there' in 'there is missing' here is extremely formal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 'one' in this way is ***not*** informal. It's called ***one anaphora*** and is very common.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence sounds more natural and it is used in a formal style. You can use "one"after the superlative or leave it out.